# How to edit field in django admin panel

Tags: python, django, admin, edit

I have admin panel in Django 1.8 with my code in admin.py file:

Here is part of my model:

```
TYPES_CHOICES = (
    ('normal', 'normal'),
    ('archive', 'archive'),
)
class Period(models.Model):
    date_start = models.DateTimeField(help_text='date_start')
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(help_text='date_end')
    type = models.CharField(choices=TYPES_CHOICES, default=TYPES_CHOICES[0][0], max_length=10)

class PeriodAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'date_start', 'date_end', 'description',
                    'note', 'is_published', 'is_actual', 'type', )
    search_fields = ('id', 'note', 'description', 'description_en',)
    fields = ['type', ]
```

My problem is, how to switch type field in to editable field, to switching field value form model. I can not found this is documentation.
Please for any hint.

Comment: How do you mean switch to editable field? The question is a little ambiguous

Comment: @yusuf.oguntola please check my edit.

Comment: I think you have django modelform and you want that form field value in admin right?

Answer (score 8):

I think you want to editable field on your list

```
models.py :
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

TYPES_CHOICES = (
    ('normal', 'normal'),
    ('archive', 'archive'),
)


class Period(models.Model):
    date_start = models.DateTimeField(help_text='date_start')
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(help_text='date_end')
    period_type = models.CharField(choices=TYPES_CHOICES, default=TYPES_CHOICES[0][0], max_length=10)


admins.py :
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Period


class PeriodAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'date_start', 'date_end', 'period_type',)
    list_editable = ('date_start', 'date_end', 'period_type', )


admin.site.register(Period, PeriodAdmin)
```

Comment: thanks, i was looking for "list_editable = ('date_start', 'date_end', 'period_type', )"

Comment: Than you so much.